# Convert Blob to File List in javascript

Tags: javascript, blob, filelist

I am using the following code to covert a canvas image to blob.
In order to convert the blob to a file/filelist object, I need to pass that filelist to file handler.

**Mycode:**

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("preview");
var theImage = document.getElementById("blahProfile");
theImage.src = canvas1.toDataURL();
var blob = dataURItoBlob(theImage.src);
```

Is there any way to convert that blob to a file object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File` objects contain more information than `Blob` objects, with properties like `lastModifiedDate`, and `fileName`. It doesn't make sense for your image data to have either of those properties, because it's not a file.

I assume you `FileList` handler users a `FileReader` to read `File` objects. However, the `FileReader` methods can process `Blob` objects as well (because `File` is a subclass of `Blob`). Thus, you can either:

- extract your `FileReader` code into a separate function that accepts a `Blob` or `File` (and possibly a resolution callback function) amd call that function when handling each of your `FileList` items and when processing your `Blob` of image data
- if your `FileList` handler only accesses list items by index (e.g., `myFileList[i]`) then you could fake a `FileList` simply by using an array of `Blob`s. For example, this function works with either a real `FileList` or array of `Blob`s:

  ```
  function processFileList(list) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(list[0]);
      reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
          console.log(reader.result);
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: can i add those two file properties to blob.

Comment: @madanV Sure, JavaScript allows you add new properties to anything, so you could make up a fake file name and add it as a `fileName`property on the `Blob`. It will then have whatever `fileName` you made up and attached to it. A "natural" `File` object will have a `fileName` that reflects the name of the selected file (but in your case, the `Blob` is just data and doesn't have a filename because it's not from the user's filesystem).

Comment: how can i add name property to blob object.

Answer (score 1):

```
        // const file = new File([blob], imageFile.name,{
        //     type:imageFile.type,
        //     lastModified: new Date().getTime()
        // }, 'utf-8');
        const newFiles = [File,File...]
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        newFiles.forEach(file => {
            dataTransfer.items.add(file)
        });
        // dataTransfer.files => FileList 
        // add the FileList to <input> of typr file
        input.files = dataTransfer.files;
```